не запускается бот телеграм
import aiogram
import logging
from aiogram import Router, Bot
from aiogram import Dispatcher as dp
from aiogram.filters import Command
import config
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bt = Bot(token="мой токен")
async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bt)

ошибка
ValueError: At least one bot instance is required to start polling

экземпляр бота передан, даже из файла конфиг токен напрямую вписываю, одна песня - не работает
при этом в пайчарме bt в строчке await dp.start_polling(bt) подсвечивается как warning

Предварительно создать экземпляр Dispatcher пробовали: убрать из импорта as dp и после строки создания бота дописать dp = Dispatcher()?

Вау! ,сработало, спасибо. очень странно, конечно, код целиком скопирован с моего репозитория на гитхабе, тот бот отлично функционирует и никаких ошибок связанным с этим не было

Оформил как ответ для других

Для корректной работы Dispatcher необходимо создать экземпляр класса:
from aiogram import Router, Bot, Dispatcher

bt = Bot(token="")
dp = Dispatcher()

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bt)

Оформлено из комментария
